# Difference Log vs simple returns in calculating momentum

Tags: momentum

I need to calculate the past 12 month momentum returns of a stock to compare relative performance of various assets. I am doubting what would be the (practical) difference between using log returns versus using simple returns in calculating the return over the past twelve months?

Comment: Why not calculate both and examine the differences for yourself?

Comment: The stocks in the top quintile by arithmetic returns are going to be exactly the same stocks as in the top quintile by logarithmic returns. It is a "rank preserving transformation" of the data.

Comment: So what is the benefit of using this transformation? A distribution that is more closer to a normal one? Lower skewness?